# How do you return the slot a player has selected

Tags: bukkit

In bukkit, I need a method that can return what hotkey a player has selected. I can't find a way to do this, the bukkit api doesn't have anything along those lines, is there another api that does include this?

Comment: Why not ask on the bukkit forums?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do get the held item slot:

`int itemSlot = Player.getInventory().getHeldItemSlot();`

Keep in mind, the held item slot is an index. This means that slot #1 is 0, and slot #2 is 1, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never thought of looking benind getInventory! This really helps, thank you